# In PowerShell, is there a way to get the text of a URL without using a browser?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

The site itself has to be logged into-which I do as a "ghost user" using the COM object. There is a page with a table that I'm able to copy by sending keystrokes, collecting a list of urls/ids/other info, which is saved to the clipboard/text file. With the com object, I'm able to open each url element from that file(as long as I'm logged in) and get the page text in the document request, but only after the page has loaded(too soon returns a partial page).

This is extremely slow over 15,000 pages/urls and I was hoping to improve that speed without having to render each url(I even have to put each one in a loop with checks just in case it fails to load)

Is there a way to grab the various label:LabelValue properties from the URL of a webpage without loading it? Edit* I have the code:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$user = "me"; $pw = "pw"
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("https://Loginscreen.com")
$userField = $ie.document.getElementByID('login')
$usernamefield.value = "$user"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('password')
$passwordfield.value = "$pw"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('SubmitLogin')
$Link.click()
$ieProc = Get-Process | ? { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.HWND }
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($ieProc.Id)
$fc = gc "C:\TempProject.txt"
foreach ($f in $fc)
{
  $url = $f.split("`t")[-1]
  $HTML = Invoke-WebRequest $url 
  $body = $HTML.ParsedHTML.body.innerText
  $body
}
```

However, it seems to be returning generic information about the login page.....I couldn't find any reference to anything on the webpage that I wanted-either HTML tag info or the text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "Is there a way to get the text of a URL without using a browser?" the answer is an overwhelming and resounding Yes!  Try Invoke-WebRequest and see if the Content property has what you are looking for.  Scraping HTML out of text is still something you will need to do manually or use a different package to scrape your juicy bits from the fruit.